# How to seal edges of plumbing work for noise isolation.

Tags: sound-proofing

I am looking into sealing some plumbing edges for noise isolation. 
The plumbing goes between two levels. The levels are separated by some amount of concrete. I don't know the depth, but it is considerate.

What materials would be ideal for this? I had in mind caulking the edges of the pipes where they go through the concrete, but maybe my first idea is incorrect.

Thanks>

Answer (score 1):

In many locales, fire protection regulations require that all holes between levels be sealed to prevent easy spread of flames.  This is most often done with a [fire retardant foam spray](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-12-oz-Fire-Block-Foam-FB-Foam/203281270).

[image: fire foam]

This should also reduce noise transmission between levels. Two for the price of one!

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```